# For CSS, vertical margin collapses, but why floated divs don't collapse vertical margins?

Tags: css

For CSS, we know that vertical margin collapses, such as in example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rbxL7/5/

(The vertical margin between the divs are only 30px.)

But what about floated divs?   Why do the vertical margins not collapse?

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rbxL7/3/

(the horizontal and vertical margins between the divs both end up as 60px).

Comment: Are you asking for a reason, or a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two
>   or more boxes (which might or might
>   not be siblings) can combine to form a
>   single margin.

and...

> Two margins are adjoining if and only
>   if:
>
> 1) both belong to in-flow block-level
>   boxes that **participate in the same
>   block formatting context**

[which leads to](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)...

> **Floats**, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
>   inline-blocks, table-cells, and
>   table-captions) that are not block
>   boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow'
>   other than 'visible' (except when that
>   value has been propagated to the
>   viewport) **establish new block
>   formatting contexts for their
>   contents**.

Comment: so... why that reasoning... or essentially it is saying: "floated divs vertical margins don't collapse"

Comment: Yeah, "floated divs vertical margins don't collapse" is the short version :-)

Comment: Another short version would be margins only collapse for items in the same block formatting context, and floats create a new block formatting context.

Comment: the spec might be a bit fuzzy if it says "can collapse"?  Does that mean a browser is standard compliant if it choose not to collapse it, because the spec says "can collapse" but not "should" or "must" collapse?

Comment: @動靜能量: "can" is not in the same group as "should" or "must", so it's totally irrelevant to what you're asking about spec fuzziness. Margins are supposed to collapse, "can" is just an English word here to mean that they are capable of doing so at all. Review [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt). As to "why", well, you can ask on a forum or W3C'S CSS mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
.outer { width: 600px; border: 1px dashed blue; overflow: hidden }  /* overflow: hidden is to clear the float if any */
.inner { float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px dashed orange; margin: 30px 0 0 30px; }
.outer .inner:last-child { margin: 30px; }
```

(If you target browsers don't support `last-child`, then add a class to the last child)

See http://jsfiddle.net/rbxL7/6/

Comment: it is not how to make it 30px.  it is "why"

Comment: yea, but it might help some one else who stumbles across this answer